# How to determine that an AWS EC2 instance is still initialising from a script

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, timeout, aws-cli

Is there a way to determine through a command line interface or other trick if an AWS EC2 instance is ready to receive `ssh` connections?

The `running` state seems not to be enough. Trying to connect in in the first minutes of the `running` state, the machine `Status checks` still shows `initialising` and `ssh` times out while trying to connect.

(I am using the `awscli` [pip](https://pip.pypa.io) package.)

Answer (score 0):

Running is similar to turning a computer on and finishing a bios check. As far as the hypervisor is concerned your instance is on.

The best way to know when your instance is ready, is to run a script at the end of startup (or when certain services are on) that will report its status to some other listener. Using that data, or event, you should know that your instance is ready to be connected to. This is purposely vague since there are so many different ways this can be accomplished.

You could also time the expected startup time, and try to connect after that and retry the connection if it fails. Still need a point at which you would stop trying as instances can fail to launch in some cases.